# Service to maintain database of airports, runways, helipads, navaid and fixes

Tags: airport, runways, waypoint

I had asked previously for a list of all the data I mention but now would like to be able to maintain this list.  I know this is not a site for software developers but does anyone know of a site that has an API to check for addition, deletions, or modifications to this data?

I have found some of the data from the FAA that is on ARCGIS but some are missing.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the d-TPP webpage are downloadable ZIP files.  File "E" has a XML file that catalogs changes to the plates in the current update cycle.

https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dtpp/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most of this information is on an update cycle.  Whether changes are made or not, old information expires.  You don’t need a special app to look for changes, just ensure your data is current per the schedule.  There are several subscription providers who support their hardware and software platforms that will prompt you to download correct versions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am actually looking for a source of this information and am going to write my own program to update my database.

Comment: Ok, well you specifically asked about maintaining current data, so I assumed you had a source already.

Comment: I probably didn't phrase my question very well.  I loaded all the data from the FAA static csv files but now want to keep it updated.  I have contacted Jeppesen to see what services they have.

Comment: But can you not write a routine to reperform the download at scheduled intervals?

Comment: I want it to be totally automated and run from a web server so scheduled downloads unfortunately would not be an option.

Comment: Tell me if I'm being too nosy about something proprietary you hope to profit from, but perhaps if we understood what you are trying to accomplish we might be able to help more.  (i.e. what are you trying to automate?)  And it's hard to know how much you already know, but have you looked into pulling from NOTAMs?